# editText.toString=="something" always false

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to check if text in editText is equal to some string.
This is my if statement (it comes every time I press a button):

`if(tx.getText().toString()=="bla")`

This is tx:
`tx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

I don't know why but the if is never true. I tried to check it by toast this way:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tx.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And it is "bla" but still its false. Why?

Comment: you can use tx.getText().toString().equals("bla") in place of == and its work.

Answer (score 4):

You should use equals

```
if(tx.getText().toString().equals("bla"))
```

equals compares the string, but == compares the objects.

As `@Frank` suggested in order to avoid NPE compare like this

```
if("bla".equals(tx.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: and put the "bla" literal first, avoid nullpointers..

Comment: thank you very much. im sorry for this stupid question i will try to search more next time, i tought this is something more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You have not use "==" for testing equality of two strings.Use `equals` method of String class.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare two `String` objects, you don't compare their literal value. You check if they are the same object, which is usually not the case. That's why you want to use `mystring.equals("my string litereal")` instead.